# Copying the full path of a file to text file

Tags: shell, filenames

I want to get the full path of all files in a directory and and the entire path has to be saved in one text file. Can you give me the script for that?

Answer (score 3):

GNU coreutils contains the `realpath` program that returns the full path for each argument. The following program prints the full name of all files in the current directory (not expanding symlinks, `-s`; not recursive):

```
realpath -s *
```

Depending on your shell, hidden dot-files will not get expanded. For that, you also need to execute `shops -s dotglob`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `readlink` (available in GNU coreutils):

```
readlink - print resolved symbolic links or canonical file names
```

Syntax:

```
readlink -f <file-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell variable `PWD` contains the full path to the current directory.

You can use `printf '%s\n'` to print a list of strings with a newline after each string.

```
printf '%s\n' "$PWD"/* >somefile.txt
```

The wildcard pattern `*` excludes dot files (files whose name begins with a `.`). If there are dot files, you can use `printf '%s\n' "$PWD"/.* "$PWD"/* >somefile.txt`; note that this also lists `.` and `..`.